# Xilinx Xpower Analyzer: Expected scope definition in VCD

Tags: power, fpga, xilinx

I use a VCD file to evaluate the power of my design. The VCD is generated using the following command in the testbench file.

```
$dumpfile ("testb.vcd");
$dumpvars (0, tb.gcm_tb);
```

`tb` is the module name of the testbench. `gcm_tb` is the instantiated name of my design.

Xpower (version 10.1) gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:Power:976 - Parsing Error parse error line 7825 Expected scope definition here
```

I notice that if I change the parameter into

```
$dumpvars (1, tb.gcm_tb);
```

then it does not give me the error. However, my design has several levels. Recording the power of only one level is not accurate.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Ask your Xilinx FAE. Search their support database.

Comment: @BrianCarlton, I am using a academic license. How to I access the FAE and database? I tried to google, but no one answer this problem previously. I also post on the xilinx website.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what is going wrong, but these are the two lines I use in a modelsim '.do' script to get a .vcd file. The '.do' file is just a tcl script, so I assume you can adapt it quite easily or maybe even use it directly in Xpower.

```
vcd file output.vcd
# add all the appropriate signals (only inputs) to the vcd, -r, recursively
vcd add -in -r *
```

Comment: what do those lines mean?

Comment: The first tells Modelsim to set a vcd output file (output.vcd), the next line adds all the inputs of the design to the .vcd file, the '-r' makes this recursive so all the design levels are added. It could help you build a separate .vcd file to send through Xpower.

Comment: This is not a forum but a Q & A site.  Putting what appears to be another question into an answer field is not proper usage.  If you have a question, post it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a more recent version, if possible. ISE 10.1 is pretty old, 14.4 is current. I only use 10.x when I need to target old parts such as Spartan 2.

Comment: ok. I will try and post what happen here.